# How to implement web share api and push notification in react-native webview?

Tags: android, webview, react-native, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to create an app shell for my PWA using react native's webview. But web share API and push notification are not working in android app.

I have created a PWA using reactjs and had used Web Share API along with push notification service. Now I am using WebView from 'react-native-webview' (version "6.9.0") library in my react-native (version "0.59.8") app to create an app shell for my PWA.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
   <WebView
      source={{ uri: "https://mypwa.firebaseapp.com" }}
   />
</View>
```

PWA is working fine on chrome browser but it's not in react-native's android app.

**Update 1:**
Those who are looking for Web Share API solution, I found way out:

```
#In react-native app:
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import Share from 'react-native-share';

nativeShare = async (data) => {
    const shareOptions = {
      title: 'Share via',
      subject: data.subject,
      message: data.message,
      url: data.url
    }
    await Share.open(shareOptions)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: "https://examplepwa.firebaseapp.com" }}
          onMessage={event => { this.nativeShare(JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data)) }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

#In PWA share service:
const webShare = (data) => {
    let { title, text, url } = data
    if (!url) {
        url = document.location.href;
    }
    if (navigator.share) {
        navigator.share({ title, text, url })
            .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
            .catch((error) => console.error('Error sharing ' + error));
    } else if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
        const shareObject = { subject: title, message: text, url }
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(shareObject))
    } else {
        console.warn('web share not supported');
    }
}
```

But I am still looking for push notification solution.